# How do I write multiple text files from embedded for loop in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, unix

I have this bash loop below which uses perl script. It is expected to output something for every `$i` in every `$f` which I want to save as separate text file. The code I have below does the job, but instead of saving for individual `$i`, it saves for `$f` and puts the output of `18 to 24` in one file. May be I have to reposition the write command in this loop or is there a better way to do this?

```
for f in *.fastq; do 
echo "Processing: " $f
for i in $(seq 18 24); do
echo "Doing: " $i
perl /home/owner/perl/count.pl $f $i
done > >(tee /media/owner/${f}_${i}.txt) 2>&1
done
```

Comment: Loop redirections apply to the entire loop, not each iteration.

Comment: Ok. so is there a way to write for $i output? Thanks

Comment: Use the redirection on the `perl` command instead. Or create a `{ group; }` and redirect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirections on loops are per loop, not per iterations.

You can instead use a `{ command group; }` around the commands you want and redirect that:

```
for f in *.fastq;
do 
  echo "Processing: " $f
  for i in $(seq 18 24);
  do
    {
      echo "Doing: " $i
      perl /home/owner/perl/count.pl $f $i
    } > >(tee /media/owner/${f}_${i}.txt) 2>&1
  done
done
```